# Reading BLOB to byte array in SQLite table

Tags: c#, sqlite, blob

I want to read a blob to a byte array and show the current byte array in the cmd.

This is my code at the moment:

```
string connector = @"data source=C:\testfile; Version=3;";

SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connector);
SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection);

connection.Open();

command.CommandText = "SELECT file FROM users";

SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    int i = 0;

    byte[] bytBLOB = new byte[reader.GetBytes(0, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue) - 1];
    reader.GetBytes(0, 0, bytBLOB, 0, bytBLOB.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(bytBLOB.ToString());

    i++;    
}
```

Currently my code doesn't work. It just prints out two lines of (I've got two items in "file"):

> System.Byte[]
>   System.Byte[]

How to get my code working. Reading all relevant posts to blob in c# doesn't help me in this situation. I used this help: [blogpost](http://fredgan.wordpress.com/2008/08/01/read-write-blobs-from-to-sqlite-using-c-net-datareader/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ToString()` doesn't work like you expect on a `byte[]`.  You'll need something like:

```
Console.WriteLine( Encoding.Default.GetString( bytBLOB ) ) ;
```

assuming the bytes in the blob represent printable characters in the default encoding.  If they're random data, you'll need to dump them byte-by-byte.